# very huge matrix in C programming

Tags: c, matrix

Good day everyone,

I'm new in C programming and I don't have a lot of knowledge on how to handle very huge matrix in C. e.g. Matrix size of 30.000 x 30.000.

My first approach is to store dynamically memory:

```
int main()
{      int **mat;
    int j;
    mat = (int **)malloc(R*sizeof(int*));
    for(j=0;j<R;j++)
        mat[j]=(int*)malloc(P*sizeof(int));
}
```

And it is a good idea to handle +/- matrix of 8.000 x 8.000. But, not bigger. So, I want to ask for any *light* to handle this kind of huge matrix, please.

As I said before: I am new to C, so please don't expect too much experience.

**Thanks in advance for any suggestion,**

David Alejandro.

PD: My laptop conf is linux ubuntu, 64bit, i7, and 4gb of ram.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with these matrices? Why isn't that approach good for larger matrices? What are you encountering exactly? Note that with the right configs, with 64bit system - I think you can allocate more then enough space even for 30,000x30,000 matrix. If it doesn't fit in RAM the OS will swap the data to disk as good as it can

Comment: So 30k*30k*4 bytes is about 3.6GB, if you have 4GB of RAM that's not a lot of head room to do stuff with the matrix. What are you planning to do with it? If you're doing matrix math/manipulation, check out LAPACK and consider using a sparse representation, if appropriate.

Comment: @MarkElliot: 4GB is not a bound, his system is 64bits, so thanks to virtual memory - with the right configurations, he can allocate much more then 4GB, the OS will swap some of the data to the disk and load it when needed.

Comment: hi Amit, I'm planning to do a simple sum on different cells based on a  previous defined relations of pairs... I've read that is possible to do it by two ways... mmap or using floating points... But neither of those ones I don't know how to handle them...

Comment: @amit the real issue is that matrix math is already pretty memory intensive and doing the computations while waiting on swap is going to make this unusably slow.

Comment: what would be the best configuration? I also have to add that I'm compiling with g++ and not with the intel compiler, which allows to compile a code that fit on 64 bits

Comment: @MarkElliot: That's why I asked what he's planning to do, if the calculations "obey" the [principle of locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality) - it might not be much of an issue, especially if the program can be parallelized - so during a page fault, other thread can get CPU time.

Comment: @DavidAlejandro: Do these calculations follow the [principle of locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality)? Or are matrix accesses random/unpredictable? Can the calculation be parallelized? These are important questions you should answer when designing systems that handle large data.

Comment: I feel "old fashioned" mentioning this but if you are running out of memory have you thought of using a memory mapped file? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) It was a technique I used a long time ago when memory was tight in Windows 3.1 :)

Comment: @DavidAlejandro - Are you using C++ or C? You are mixing `printf` with `cout` - which is not a good idea.

Comment: Also, How are the arrays A and B being initialised?

Comment: Thanks @EdHeal, I corrected it. Ed, would you recommend to me some literature about your suggestion: _int *matrix = (int *)malloc(R * P * sizeof(int));_ It looks more practical and faster to handle very huge matrix.

Comment: In C, you don't want the casts for malloc()s return value, either. Instead: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @wildplasser - You are correct. Been a while since I have used `malloc`. Been converted to the joys of C++

Comment: ok, thanks for all the advises! (:

Comment: I don't want to do the step, cos C++ is not so friendly to handle files, may be I need a little more grasp

Comment: @DavidAlejandro - Drop me an email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a matrix as large as that, I would try to avoid all those calls to `malloc`. This will reduce the time to set up the datastructure and remove the memory overhead with dynamic memory (`malloc` stores additional information as to the size of the chunk)

Just use `malloc` once - i.e:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int *matrix = malloc(R * P * sizeof(int));
```

Then to compute the index as

```
index = column + row * P;
```

Also access the memory sequentially i.e. by column first. Better performance for the cache.

Comment: How do you recommend me to add just 1 to a specific cell. Usually, in the traditional way, it is:  _A[i][j]=A[i][j]+1;_

Comment: @DavidAlejandro: no. Just create an (inline) function to implement the 2d to 1d index conversion for you. The double indexing is really a killer.

Comment: @DavidAlejandro - As you are using C, just write a macro to do this. i.e. `#define INDEX(r, c) ((c) + (r) * P);` Then `A[INDEX(i, j)] = A[INDEX(i, j)] + 1;`

Comment: @EdHeal I've tested your suggestion. But the compiler prompted to me: **Ensayo.cpp:200112:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token** But, I cannot see how to understand it

Comment: Also, when I tried to define the matrix, the compiler prompted to me: **Ensayo.cpp:200056:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]**

Comment: **if( strcmp(string,"0") == 0 )** in a function to convert a 'string' number to an 'int' number

Answer (score 1):

Well, a two-dimensional array (roughly analogous C representation of a matrix) of `30000 * 30000` `ints`, assuming 4 bytes per `int`, would occupy `3.6 * 10^9` bytes, or ~3.35 gigabytes. No conventional system is going to allow you to allocate that much static virtual memory at compile time, and I'm not certain you could successfully allocate it dynamically with `malloc()` either. If you only need to represent a small numerical range, then you could drastically (i.e., by a factor of 4) reduce your program's memory consumption by using `char`. If you need to do something like, e.g., assign boolean values to specific numbers corresponding to the indices of the array, you could perhaps use bitsets and further curtail your memory consumption (by a factor of 32). Otherwise, the only viable approach would involve working with smaller subsets of the matrix, possibly saving intermediate results to disk if necessary.

If you could elaborate on how you intend to use these massive matrices, we might be able to offer some more specific advice.

Comment: How would it be to handle bitsets? Would you recommend to me any bibliography? please

Comment: Based on your update, bitsets don't appear to be appropriate for your purposes. They would be suitable if you were trying to, for example, flag certain numbers represented by the indices of the bitset as being true or false w/r/t some criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are declaring your values as `float` rather than `double`, your array will be about 3.4 GB in size.  As long as you only need one, and you have virtual memory on your Ubuntu system, I think you could just code this in the obvious way.

If you need multiple matrices this large, you might want to think about:

- Putting a lot more RAM into your computer.
- Renting time on a computing cluster, and using cluster-based processing to compute the values you need.
- Rewriting your code to work on subsets of your data, and write each subset out to disk and free the memory before reading in the next subset.

You might want to do a Google search for "processing large data sets"

Comment: I already googled. But, do it on handling just arrays... wouldn't be expensive on time and _I would say_ memory?

Comment: Memory is not as expensive as it used to be.  If you will be processing very large arrays, very often, you might want to just buy more memory for your computer.  64-bit Ubuntu can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to add comments so dropping an answer here.

1 thing tha I can think is, you are not going to get those values in running program. Those will come from some files only. So instead taking all values, keep reading 30,000x2 one by one so that will not come into memory.

For 30k*30k matrix, if init value is 0(or same) for all elements what you can do is, instead creating the whole matrix, create a matrix of 60k*3 (3 cols will be : row no, col no and value). This is becasue you will have max 60k different location which will be affected.

I know this is going to be a little slow because you always need to see if the element is already added or not. So, ***if speed is not your concern***, this will work.